# Oracle: Create a function that returns a set of values?

Tags: oracle, function

I have a table of keywords

```
select * from keywords;

id kw    
-- --    
 1 foo 
 1 bar   
 2 foo
```

and a query that will select rows from a master table based on those keywords.

```
select id, stuff from assets
 where id in (select unique id from keywords where kw = 'foo');

id stuff
-- -----
 1   ...
 2   ...
```

How can I turn the subquery into a function?  i.e. I would like a function to return a set of values that can be used by an IN clause.

```
select id, stuff from assets
 where id in HAS_KEYWORD('foo');
```

Comment: A pipelined table function could be a solution for you but (1) it would make the code more complicated. Something like `... id in (select * from table(pipelined_function('foo')))` (2) Any solution would be less efficient than a subquery

Comment: @ms32035, would you mind providing an example of the syntax to do that?

Comment: A function would only return one value, otherwise it wouldn't be a function. A list of values is returned by a View, for example. You would still need the subquery, but you can move the WHERE - and potentially GROUP BY/HAVING - clause to the view definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table names differ a bit but the solution works

```
    create table tab (  
      key number,
      val number
      );

    create table foe(
      col1 number,
      col2 varchar2(3)
    );

    insert into tab values (0,3);
    insert into tab values (1,4);
    insert into tab values (2,5);

    insert into foe values (3,'YES');
    insert into foe values (4,'YES');
    insert into foe values (5,'NO');

    create type t_return is table of number;
    /
    create or replace function fnc(str varchar2) 
      return t_return pipelined is
    begin
      for rec in (select col1 from foe where col2 = str) loop
        pipe row(rec.col1);
      end loop;
    end;
    /

    select * from tab where val in (select * from table(fnc('YES')))
```